# What does the 'profile_listings_and_forms' permission allow?

Tags: permissions

I'm currently reviewing the permissions for a CiviCRM/WordPress site and want to make sure that I understand the permissions correctly before changing them.

I've found the [documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/#using-the-profile-listings-and-forms-permission) on the `profile_listings_and_forms` permission to be a bit unclear so I just wanted to check. Am I right in thinking that this permission is just a shorthand for allowing all four of the other profile permissions?

i.e. `profile_listings_and_forms` = `profile_create` + `profile_edit` + `profile_view` + `profile_listings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `profile_listings_and_forms` permission is just a shorthand for allowing all four profile permissions.

`profile_listings_and_forms` = `profile_create` + `profile_edit` + `profile_view` + `profile_listings`

The documentation is being updated to clarify this.

Thanks to MikeMJCO for [confirming this](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-user-guide/issues/355#issuecomment-422122879).